# List assertion by assertThat (Assertj)

Tags: java, list, selenium, automation, assertions

Usually when we send List type of expected and actual values, assertThat will perform mentioned assert type on these values. But since I upgrade my Java to 8, those assertions or showing compilation errors. Following is my sample test code on assertions :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

public class VerificationTest {


    public void listTest(List<?> expectedList, List<?> actualList){
        Iterable<?> actualIterable = actualList;
        Iterable<?> expectedIterable = expectedList;
        assertThat(actualIterable).describedAs("List Test").containsAll(expectedIterable);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        List<String> listOne = new ArrayList<>();
        listOne.add("A");
        listOne.add("B");
        listOne.add("C");

        List<String> listTwo = new ArrayList<>();
        listTwo.add("A");
        listTwo.add("B");
        listTwo.add("C");
        listTwo.add("D");

        VerificationTest verificationTest = new VerificationTest();
        verificationTest.listTest(listOne, listTwo);
    }
}
```

Following is the error that I am getting :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The method hasSameElementsAs(Iterable<? extends capture#1-of ?>) in the type AbstractIterableAssert<capture#2-of ?,capture#3-of ? extends List<? extends capture#1-of ?>,capture#1-of ?> is not applicable for the arguments (List<capture#5-of ?>)
```

What was the issue here? Is this because of Java 8?

Thank you